# I've been having the error instance member 'object' cannot be used on type ___

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm working on my Udacity Nanodegree iOS project and it requires that we use a shared model with the AppDelegate. I've been having this error in my code for a while an I have looked to the internet for solutions. I tried using a get only declaration and I'm still getting thrown this error... any suggestions?
Here's part of my CollectionViewController.swift:

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit


    class SentMemesCollectionVC:UICollectionViewController{
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
  let object = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
  var appDelegate = AppDelegate() {
        return object as! AppDelegate //Error get only property //error instance member 'object' cannot be used on type ___
    }

        override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return appDelegate.memes.count
        }

        let memes = appDelegate.memes

        override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CustomMemeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomMemeCell
            let meme = memes[indexPath.item]
            cell.setText(meme.top, bottomString: meme.bottom)
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: meme.image)
            cell.backgroundView = imageView

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: why you don't use `let object = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` and `return object.memes.count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create/use a computed property!? That should look like this:

```
var appDelegate : AppDelegate {
    return object as! AppDelegate
}
```

Comment: I am using a computed property.. this was suggested to me.. I don't exactly understand why though... I believe everything that I am trying to get from the AppDelegate is definitively set in my code as a value not a type

Comment: @HarryMerzin sorry for the typo in the answer, does that code work for you?

Comment: the code did work to eliminate the error in the current place but now the error is moved to `let memes = appDelegate.Memes`... should I try those same steps on everything if the error if it keeps getting pushed down??]

Comment: @HarryMerzin no, that line should actually work - what is the error message there?

Comment: the error is:  `Instance member 'appDelegate' cannot be used on type 'SentMemesCollectionVC'`  @luk2302

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me either as the instance member is clearly defined and not getting anything from the ViewController it's in... Is it being confused as a set? should the VC inherit more? @luk2302